flutter runtime failed assertion renderer.parent != null
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 3345 pos 14: 'renderer.parent != null': is not true.
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
#2      RenderObject.getTransformTo (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:3345:14)
#3      ScrollPosition.ensureVisible (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart:809:28)
#4      ScrollableState._performEnsureVisible (package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart:1041:55)
#5      Scrollable.ensureVisible (package:flutter/src/widgets/scrollable.dart:475:45)
#6      _DropdownMenuState.scrollToHighlight.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/dropdown_menu.dart:450:20)
#7      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1386:15)
#8      SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1322:11)
#9      SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1169:5)
#10     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:312:13)
#11     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:399:5)
#12     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:283:31)


Can you add some code?

You need to post the whole code so that  we would be able to help
